# Williamson Ether synthesis use of particular solvent

Tags: solvents, ethers

In Williamson ether synthesis conjugate acid of corresponding alkoxide ion is taken as solvent instead of any other alcohol. Why it is like that?

Comment: What could happen if you were using methoxide base and ethanol as solvent?

Answer (score 3):

The $\text{p}K_a$ of alkyl alcohols* are close to each other; the public compilation by the [Bordwell table](https://organicchemistrydata.org/hansreich/resources/pka/#kaalcohol) for example lists MeOH (29.0), EtOH (29.8), iPrOH (30.3).  If one assumes the exhaustive deprotonation e.g., of MeOH by sodium to yield $\ce{MeO^-}$ and $\ce{Na+}$, this newly generated based is capable to move the equilibria of

$$\ce{EtOH + MeO^- <=> EtO^- + MeOH}$$
$$\ce{iPrOH + MeO^- <=> iPrO^- + MeOH}$$

sufficiently to the right hand side that -- if the molar ratio of e.g. $\ce{MeO^-}$ and EtOH is big enough -- these additional nucleophiles interfere with the Willamson reaction.  Instead of only

$$\ce{RCH2-Cl + MeO^- -> RCH2-OMe + Cl^-}$$

you are going to observe substantial amounts of side product along

$$\ce{RCH2-Cl + EtO^- -> RCH2-OEt + Cl^-}$$

which can alter the both physical properties of the product (crystallinity, melting point, etc) as well as chemical and [ADMET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADME) characteristics.

* The reason to highlight *alkyl* alcohols is that phenols are substantially more acidic because of an easier stabilization of the negative charge of the anion.  In both cases, though, electron withdrawing substitution can increase the acidity / lower the relevant $\text{p}K_a$ value.